# How to change the keys of a dictionary from keys of another dictionary in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict1:{Name:"Alex", 3: "61"}`. I have created a duplicate dictionary `dict2` containing the same key-value pairs in it. And I send dict2 as an parameter to a function which then converts to theses values: `dict2={1: "Alex",undefined: "61"}`.

Can someone help me write code that replaces the `undefined:61` to the one present in the original dict? The final dict has to be: `dict={1: "Alex",3: "61"};`

```
dict1={Name:"Alex", 3: "61"};
dict2={Name:"Alex", 3: "61"}; //created a copy of original dictionary
function(dict2){
     //some function that converts dict2 to the following value.
}
console.log(dict2);   //dict2={1: "Alex",undefined: "61"}

//now i want to write the code to substitute the undefined key-value pair to the one present in the original.
//my final dict has to be as follows:
dict={1: "Alex",3: "61"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Get and store the value of property `"undefined"`, `delete` `"undefined"` property; iterate properties, values of `dict1`, if value of property matches stored value, set property at `dict2` to property name matched at `dict1` set stored variable to value of set property.

```js
dict1 = {
  Name: "Alex",
  3: "61"
};

dict2 = {
  1: "Alex",
  undefined: "61"
};

let {undefined:val} = dict2;

delete dict2["undefined"];

for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(dict1)) {
  if (prop === val) dict2[key] = val;
}

console.log(dict2);
```

Comment: The approach returns expected result described at OP. You can alternatively use `JSON.stringify()`, `.replace()` `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dict2).replace(/undefined/, 3))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Iterate over first object(dict1) and create a new object, lets say temp where key and values are reversed. So temp looks like {Alex:Name, 61:3}.
2. Iterate over dict2 and at the key "undefined", get the value( 61 in this case), then read the value from the reversed object to get 3. Use this as key(3) and put value(61).
3. delete the key "undefined" from dict2.

```js
var dict1 = {
  Name: "Alex",
  3: "61"
};
var dict2 = {
  1: "Alex",
  undefined: "61"
};
var temp = {};
for (var i in dict1) {
  temp[dict1[i]] = i;
}

for (var key in dict2) {
  if (key == "undefined") {
    var val = dict2[key];
    dict2[temp[val]] = val;
  }
}
delete dict2["undefined"];
console.log(dict2);
```

Comment: ...this code is working fine for only one undefined value. when I'm trying with this dictionary,  var dict2 = {
  1: "Alex",
  undefined: "61",
  undefined:"London"
}; ,the following code is failing

Comment: var dict1= { 1: "Alex", age: "61", home:"London" }; var dict2 = { 1: "Alex", undefined: "61", undefined:"London" }; the following code isnt working. can you fix it?

Comment: @Kenz In javascript, objects can have only one key. In your case, you have undefined as a key in two places. The second one would overwrite the first one.So your `dict2` would look like { 1: "Alex", undefined:"London"} , In other words your object can only ever have one key as undefined and in that case solution works.

Comment: what can be the  alternative  for a dict that can take key-value pairs

Comment: @Kenz You can use object but you have to ensure the keys are different. Is it possible to create keys like undefined1, undefined2 etc. instead of `undefined`.in your case?